# javascript alert() equivalent in ftl file

Tags: freemarker

Do we have anything equivalent to javascript alert() in ftl file to display variable values?

I tried using javascript also in ftl like below but didnt help:

```
<#assign myuser= "value">
<script type="text/javascript">   
alert("${myuser}")
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, your code should work, and display an alert dialog containing text `value` in your browser. I hope you're aware, that Freemarker runs **server-side**, generates a HTML (or other) content, which is then sent to and processed by a **browser**.

Comment: Thanks Jozef!
Do you know how it will work for soy file?